# lambda layers with Serverless Framework Composing services

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, serverless-framework

I'm trying to deploy several services to an AWS account using the Serverless Framework Composing method.

In the `infrastructure` service, I'm setting up some resources like S3, CloudFront, ApiGateway... etc
and deploying a Lambda functions with a shared python layer using the npm package `serverless-python-requirements`

Then I pass this lambda layer to another service to use it,
but when I update the infrastructure, the lambda layer changes and passes the new name to the other services. However, the other services give me an error message like this:

> Resource handler returned message: "Layer version arn:aws:lambda:xxxx:yyyyy:layer:infrastructure-dev-python-requirements:14 does not exist. (Service: Lambda, Status Code: 400, Request ID: zzzzzz)"

It seems that AWS is still looking for the old version of my layer, which has been overwritten by the infrastructure service. How can I make the other services use the updated python layer?

project file structure:

```
 - serverless-compose.yml
 - infrastructure
   - serverless.yml

 - backend-admin
   - serverless.yml

 - backend-member
   - serverless.yml
```

```
// serverless-compose.yml
services:
  infrastructure:
    path: infrastructure

  backend-admin:
    path: backend-admin
    dependsOn:
      - infrastructure
    params:
      AttachmentsBucket: ${infrastructure.AttachmentsBucket}
      WebAppBucketClient: ${infrastructure.WebAppBucketClient}
      WebAppBucketAdmin: ${infrastructure.WebAppBucketAdmin}
      CognitoUserPoolARN: ${infrastructure.CognitoUserPoolARN}
      ApiGatewayAuthorizer: ${infrastructure.ApiGatewayAuthorizer}
      ApiGatewayRestApi: ${infrastructure.ApiGatewayRestApi}
      ApiGatewayResourceId: ${infrastructure.ApiGatewayResourceId}
      PythonLambdaLayer: ${infrastructure.PythonRequirementsLambdaLayerQualifiedArn}

  backend-member-1:
    path: backend-member-1
    dependsOn:
      - backend-admin
    params:
      AttachmentsBucket: ${infrastructure.AttachmentsBucket}
      WebAppBucketClient: ${infrastructure.WebAppBucketClient}
      WebAppBucketAdmin: ${infrastructure.WebAppBucketAdmin}
      CognitoUserPoolARN: ${infrastructure.CognitoUserPoolARN}
      ApiGatewayAuthorizer: ${infrastructure.ApiGatewayAuthorizer}
      ApiGatewayRestApi: ${infrastructure.ApiGatewayRestApi}
      ApiGatewayResourceId: ${infrastructure.ApiGatewayResourceId}
      PythonLambdaLayer: ${infrastructure.PythonRequirementsLambdaLayerQualifiedArn}
```

```
// backend-admin/api/ProfileFunctions.py
some python code

// backend-admin/api/ProfileFunctions.yml
AdminTestGet:
  handler: api/ProfileFunctions.admin_test_get
  events:
    - http:
        path: /admin/profile
        method: get
        cors: true
        authorizer:
          type: COGNITO_USER_POOLS
          authorizerId: ${param:ApiGatewayAuthorizer}  <---- you can see here how params passed
          scopes:
            - aws.cognito.signin.user.admin
  layers:
    - ${param:PythonLambdaLayer} <---- you can see here how params passed
```